# parted: create new partition

Tags: luks, parted

I have a 3TB disk, and I understand I have to use `parted` if I want to create a partition bigger than 2TB. All right then.

```
parted /dev/sdb

(parted) mklabel gpt

(parted) mkpart primary                                          
File system type?  [ext2]?
```

Say what? It does not let me to create a partition without specifying a FS type. Why does `parted` insist on specifying a FS type. AFAIU, a FS type is completly independent from a partition.

In `man parted`, I read that:

```
fs-type can be one of "fat16", "fat32", "ext2", "linux-swap", or "reiserfs".
```

I don't want any of these. I want to create a partition to be used as LUKS partition. What should I select?

Comment: Fstype data goes in the partition table in addition to being in a header in the partition itself. You must set some value. Also who said you have to use parted?

Comment: fdisk said that: WARNING: The size of this disk is 3.0 TB (3000592982016 bytes). DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes larger than (2199023255040 bytes) for 512-byte sectors. Use parted(1) and GUID partition table format (GPT).

Comment: That is because you are using an old version of `fdisk` that doesn't know how to create GPT tables. You should use `gdisk` instead as a replacement although the latest `fdisk` builds include experimental support for GPT. The limitation is not so much with the tool (although in your case it is since it's old) but with the type of partition table you have to use.

Comment: Some googling turns up no reason to avoid parted, any pointers?

Comment: @jthill There is no particular reason to avoid `parted` as it is a good tool, but it is rather complex and there is less documentation and examples floating around for it. A tool like `gdisk` would be easier to substitute for `fdisk` and be able to follow generally the same instructions. Also the question made it sound like they thought `parted` was the only tool that could handle this. I thought it salient to point out that they aren't stuck with one tool they couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parted prompts and goes into an interactive mode when you do not provide enough information to create the partition with the command. The following will create a partition that spans the entire disk and will not prompt for filesystem type:

```
mkpart primary 1 -1
```